# Preferred design-pattern/architecture for specific application

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

Peace and Love!

I'm relatively new to Web Dev, focusing on PHP, JS and MySql. Until now I've practiced mainly basic "spaghetti" / procedural approach in my coding, and I think it's time to move on to study and experience OOP.

I'm starting work on a project for a small business client, where I'm developing for them from scratch an application to manage their products and customers, creation of quotes, orders, CRM and analysis (DB queries, charts etc.). something like a small tailor-made ERP.

Now, I don't know yet any of the OO design patterns out there, and my question to you - based on this kind of application - what design pattern will you consider for developing it and why?
Once I get your ideas I can focus and study one approach and start to implement it. I just don't want to study 10 patterns to just know what I should use.

p.s.1. I see lots of "MVC" flying around - could this be my answer?
p.s.2. I believe I want to program it all from scratch, not using an existing framework. This is because i wish to learn firsthand the fundamentals of OOP.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think that you should first try out an MVC framework to get yourself familiar with the pattern before trying to develop one yourself. Here there's a list of PHP MVC frameworks that I've found using Google.
[list of mvc frameworks](http://www.phpwact.org/php/mvc_frameworks)

Comment: Thanks, and the list is great ill check it up!

Answer (score 1):

MVC is the first pattern you will want to familiarize yourself with. I suggest trying out an MVC framework such as [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) to help you learn the ropes.

Comment: Thanks, I guess its MVC time!